# Flask logger does not work when served with an ASGI server like Uvicorn

Tags: python, flask, logging, uvicorn, asgi

I want to serve my Flask app with a ASGI server called Uvicorn. Turns out when I convert my app from wsgi to asgi (following instructions here https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/asgi/)  suddently app.logger function is undefined. But I really need the logging functionality to develop my app.

Please follow the steps below to reproduce the problem.

I wrote this basic app

```
from flask import Flask
from asgiref.wsgi import WsgiToAsgi

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    app.logger.info("hey I am your favourite log message")
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

app = WsgiToAsgi(app)
```

I installed uvicorn

```
pip install uvicorn
```

Ran my app

```
uvicorn app:app
```

And I get this error when the app tries to log using app.logger

```
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 373, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 75, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\wsgi.py", line 21, in __call__
    await WsgiToAsgiInstance(self.wsgi_application)(scope, receive, send)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\wsgi.py", line 51, in __call__
    await self.run_wsgi_app(body)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 444, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "C:\Users\Tamjid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 455, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "C:\Users\Tamjid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 486, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\asgiref\wsgi.py", line 140, in run_wsgi_app
    for output in self.wsgi_application(environ, self.start_response):
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "f:\projects\logger-flask\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File ".\app.py", line 8, in hello_world
    app.logger.info("hey I am your favourite log message")
AttributeError: 'WsgiToAsgi' object has no attribute 'logger'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An instance of `Flask` supports the WSGI protocol, and it also adds a number of conveniences, such as a logger. If you wrap the Flask instance and lose the reference to it, you lose those convenience methods.

Instead of

```
app = WsgiToAsgi(app)
```

try

```
wsgi = WsgiToAsgi(app)
```

then

```
uvicorn app:wsgi
```

Comment: Thanks changing the name of WsgiToAsgi instance removed the "AttributeError: 'WsgiToAsgi' object has no attribute 'logger'"

Answer (score 1):

I used different name for WsgiToAsgi instance and it removed the initial exception. But I was still getting a logging error.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tamjid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1084, in emit       
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

To solve this I added this two lines which removes the default logging handler

```
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)
```

My complete working code is here

```
from flask import Flask, current_app
from asgiref.wsgi import WsgiToAsgi
app = Flask(__name__)
from flask.logging import default_handler
app.logger.removeHandler(default_handler)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    app.logger.warning('hey I am your favourite log message')
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

wsgi = WsgiToAsgi(app)
```